# Alternative to Google Latitude?

Tags: geolocation, google-latitude

Like the title says, is there an easy way to share my location in real-time with friends without letting Google know where I am?

Comment: Don't you mean "without **you** knowing that Google knows where you are"? (just adding to the privacy complex)

Comment: Fair point. Related to that -- the "Use wireless networks" option adds a great deal of location awareness without GPS usage, but requires consenting to Google's (anonymized) collection of location data. To track your location without the wireless networks option, you're going to be running GPS constantly. TO help cut that down you could look into one of the many rules-based GPS triggers -- turn GPS on or off based on cell tower or nearby wifi networks. There are a few apps for that, such as Tasker or Locale.

Comment: I'd really like to know how to do this without a data plan.  An SMS autoresponder that replies with a google maps link to my latitude and longitude?

Comment: @endolith - I think you want something like Inserty http://www.appbrain.com/app/inserty-(free)/com.roomfour0four.android.market.inserty

Comment: I figured out how to do it with Tasker, so my phone automatically responds to SMS messages with certain keyword and sends the person a google maps link and my speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Glympse](http://glympse.com) seems like a good alternative. Just pick who you want to share with, and for how long, and they can follow you on their phones or computers (and they don't need Glympse installed).

[image: QR Code]

Comment: I have used Glympse and like the way it works. It does not require an account to use. It generates a unique URL that you send to those who you want to track you. You set the duration for how long someone can track you. I gotta believe the company that makes "Glympse" will be bought up by some corporation for big $$.

Comment: Glympse looks good, except the longest you can share your location to someone is 4 hours. No Latitude replacement.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used it myself, but I've noticed [Neer](http://www.neerlife.com/) in the market -- It sounds like what you're looking for.