# Is there a (decentralized) open source "Google Latitude" alternative?

Tags: geolocation, google-latitude

Is there an open source application which allows to share my location in real time? I'm looking for a fully open source solution, that is open source client as well as open source server software.

It doesn't have to be scalable or anything, I just want to share my location to whoever has the link to the application on my server.

<sup>This is not a duplicate of [Alternative to Google Latitude?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/alternative-to-google-latitude) - I want a self-hosted application (on my own server), not on some non-Google third party server</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OpenGTS](http://opengts.sourceforge.net/) provides fleet tracking, and there is a (paid) Android App [on the market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wiebej.gps2opengts).  Given that it's open source, it's always possible someone (you?) could develop a free app as well.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted? While OpenGTS is cool for the server side of things, the linked client side isn't open source.

Comment: Because ND Geek linked to a paid app, but a free one exists too. Here: https://code.google.com/p/android-opengts/

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: the project renamed to [OwnTracks](http://owntracks.org/)

Here's a good, open and decentralized alternative which appeared recently:

## [MQTTitude](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=st.alr.mqttitude)

#### A Google Latitude replacement based on MQTT

> MQTTitude enables a device to periodically publish its location status to your MQTT broker. If you've previously used Latitude, you can think of this as a a decentralized Latitude.

[image] [image]

## Summary:

> Whether you want to keep track of your own location or that of a family member (with their consent, of course), MQTTitude will let you do that in a safe way. There are at least two components you'll want to use: one of our Apps, and an MQTT broker.
>
> The app speaks to the broker. Other programs (we have a few for you, but you can create others yourself) speak to the broker as well. The smartphone app PUBlishes location data, and the other programs SUBscribe to that data. A program can store the data in a database, send it someplace (careful with that!), or simply discard it (which wouldn't really be useful now, would it?).
>
> For the time being documentation is, ahem, a bit lacking, but you might find something useful on our development site.

## Links

- [Website](http://mqttitude.org/)
- [API](http://mqttitude.org/api.html)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/binarybucks/mqttitude)